# Linq to XML : Parsing Unstructured Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm creating a HTML responsive page for a mobile app based on following XML structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Volumes>
<paragraph>
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <text>Apple</text>
   <page>1</page>
 <remark>(Apple Inc.) </remark>
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <explanation>Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Cupertino, California, that designs, develops, and sells consumer electronics, computer software, and online services</explanation> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <text>Dell</text>
 <remark>Dell Inc.</remark>
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <explanation>Dell Inc. is an American privately owned multinational computer technology company based in Round Rock, Texas, United States, that develops, sells, repairs, and supports computers and related products and services.</explanation> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <text>Michael Dell</text>
   <search>dell</search>
 <remark>born February 23, 1965</remark>
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <explanation> Michael Saul Dell (born February 23, 1965) is an American business magnate, investor, philanthropist, and author</explanation> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <explanation> Business Career : </explanation> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <explanation> While a freshman pre-med student at the University of Texas, Dell started an informal business putting together and selling upgrade kits for personal computers[11] in Room 2713 of the Dobie Center residential building. He then applied for a vendor license to bid on contracts for the State of Texas, winning bids by not having the overhead of a computer store</explanation> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <text>HP</text>
 <remark>Hewlett-Packard</remark>
</paragraph>
<paragraph>
 <explanation>Something here</explanation> 
</paragraph>
</Volumes>
```

Basically each *paragraph* element will create a new line of paragraph. And each element within the paragraph will define the text format.

*paragraph/text* defines the header of the paragraph. It should be followed by another *paragraph/explanation* element.
However some explanation maybe broken into multiple paragraphs.

I'm not sure how to write parser to read this file.

E.g. Output [image]

PS: I can take care of the formatting. Just need ideas to efficiently parse the document. Since each XML can be around 2-3MB.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for. Load the document using LINQ to XML... what sort of structure are you looking for after that? You need to be specific about your requirements.

Comment: Your problem is you are creating a structure that can't easily be parsed.  Think again about your structure and come up with a structure that can easily be parsed.

Comment: @jdweng, these xml files are already there and was migrated from PDF files. Total 10 files which represent one book and each book can come up to 100 pages. The initial developer who migrated the PDF to XML went underground with the code on how to represent them in HTML responsive page. (Which he demonstrated could work). New files are converted in much more structured schema. But due to timeline, I need to work with these files.

Comment: Understand the issue very well been parsing documents for over 40 years.  I'm not sure what you actually need from the text.  The problem is we are dealing with human inputs which can vary widely.  I person at one time typed the data (probably in word and got converted to pdf).  So the formatting spacing may vary significantly.  Let me try a few things and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is worth a 1000 points

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Topic> topics = new List<Topic>();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            Topic topic = null;
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if(reader.Name != "paragraph")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("paragraph");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement paragraph = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    foreach(XElement subPara in paragraph.Elements())
                    {
                        switch(subPara.Name.LocalName)
                        {
                            case "text" :
                                topic = new Topic();
                                topics.Add(topic);
                                topic.title = (string)subPara;
                                break;
                            case "page":
                                topic.page = (int?)subPara;
                                break;
                            default:
                                KeyValuePair<string, string> newPara = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                                    subPara.Name.LocalName,
                                    (string)subPara
                                );
                                topic.paragraphs.Add(newPara);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
    public class Topic
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int? page { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paragraphs { get; set; }
        public Topic()
        {
            paragraphs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: that's the perfect answer and definitely worth 1000 points, but unfortunately I don't have that much point balance :)
Just to clarify, I just don't need this for display, there are also some other functionality required that allows to search, add bookmark or notes against each topic. But I can take care of that.